# Algorithm to remove locations from a set which lie within a distance

Tags: java, algorithm, geospatial

I am looking for a solution where I have a set of locations which have some priority.

I want to remove lower priority locations such that no remaining location lies within a particular distance (say 100 meters) to any of the location.

Comment: So remove locations starting with those with lowest priority such that no location is within distance d of any other location?  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: The location set consists of 5 million locations. Removing the lowest priority location and then checking among all the remaining locations whether any location lies within distance d to any other location will get costly.

Comment: I agree, but if you want a completely accurate algorithm, I think it is unavoidable to determine distances between all points.  Does it have to be completely accurate or are "shortcuts" allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) sounds well-suited to this problem.

- If you're removing the vast majority of the points, it might make the most sense to start from the point with highest priority, and, for each point, doing something similar to nearest-neighbour search (stopping once we get a point bounded by the given distance) in the tree to check whether to insert the point.

  You may want to try to find a self-balancing variant or occasionally rebalance the tree during this process, as unbalanced trees lead to slow operations.
- If a significant portion of the points will remain, it might be better to insert all the points into the tree to start and do modified nearest-neighbour search (ignoring the point itself, bounded by distance) starting from the lowest priority and removing relevant points as we go.

  Using appropriate construction techniques, you can construct a balanced tree from the start.

Insertion and deletion takes O(log n) in a balanced tree (a simple approach to deletion is to just set a "deleted" flag in the node, but this doesn't ever make the tree smaller) and O(n) in an unbalanced tree. Nearest-neighbour search is similar, although it might take up to O(n) even for balanced trees, but this is a worst case - on average it should be closer to O(log n).

> The k-d tree is a binary tree in which every node is a k-dimensional point. Every non-leaf node can be thought of as implicitly generating a splitting hyperplane that divides the space into two parts, known as half-spaces. Points to the left of this hyperplane are represented by the left subtree of that node and points right of the hyperplane are represented by the right subtree. The hyperplane direction is chosen in the following way: every node in the tree is associated with one of the k-dimensions, with the hyperplane perpendicular to that dimension's axis. So, for example, if for a particular split the "x" axis is chosen, all points in the subtree with a smaller "x" value than the node will appear in the left subtree and all points with larger "x" value will be in the right subtree. In such a case, the hyperplane would be set by the x-value of the point, and its normal would be the unit x-axis.
>
> [image]
>
> Searching for a nearest neighbour in a k-d tree proceeds as follows:
>
> 1. Starting with the root node, the algorithm moves down the tree recursively, in the same way that it would if the search point were being inserted (i.e. it goes left or right depending on whether the point is lesser than or greater than the current node in the split dimension).
> 2. Once the algorithm reaches a leaf node, it saves that node point as the "current best"
> 3. The algorithm unwinds the recursion of the tree, performing the following steps at each node:
>
>    1. If the current node is closer than the current best, then it becomes the current best.
>    2. The algorithm checks whether there could be any points on the other side of the splitting plane that are closer to the search point than the current best. In concept, this is done by intersecting the splitting hyperplane with a hypersphere around the search point that has a radius equal to the current nearest distance. Since the hyperplanes are all axis-aligned this is implemented as a simple comparison to see whether the distance between the splitting coordinate of the search point and current node is lesser than the distance (overall coordinates) from the search point to the current best.
>
>       1. If the hypersphere crosses the plane, there could be nearer points on the other side of the plane, so the algorithm must move down the other branch of the tree from the current node looking for closer points, following the same recursive process as the entire search.
>       2. If the hypersphere doesn't intersect the splitting plane, then the algorithm continues walking up the tree, and the entire branch on the other side of that node is eliminated.
> 4. When the algorithm finishes this process for the root node, then the search is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you meant to remove locations, starting with those with lowest priority, within a certain distance to another location.

You could use a [quad tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Point_quadtree) to represent the relative locations.  The idea is that you construct a tree where each node has four children.  Each child represents a quadrant and as you add each location, you traverse the tree.  If you hit a childless node, then you create new child nodes representing once again that same area divided into four regions until each location is in its own region.

Once you've created this tree, you can reduce the sample sizes for each distance check between locations to only those within a certain depth and only locations within the nearby quadrants.

This method however is *approximate* and doesn't guarantee that you check locations that cross entire major quadrants, however it does efficiently allow you to distance check most locations that are nearby effectively reducing the run time.  To get around this, you can create multiple quad trees from the same data with slight offsets, but of course each quad tree is going to be a multiplier factor in the run time since you will build and check each tree individually.

Does this answer your question?